# Is there a relation between `@typedef` and static members that makes them incompatible?

Tags: typescript, intellisense, jsdoc

When I write the following JavaScript, I get an error: ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?filetype=js#code/PQKhAIAEBcFMFsAOAbAhncBVcJgCgBjNAZ2PACFUAncAbz3EfFAhgE9FYATWAMzoAK1aAEtUyADyYAfAF9wAWTYAxAPaqc%20Js2Da9%207QD1jAWjPmLl8AGVo6EQXDwEAI1hUyBVADtvq6OBUfO6w3gSw4ESopODQHBGI1KjOcB54DEzAuphhqvDO3gHQGrwiAB4AXBmMWeB%203rb2jgC84ABEABawyMiqbQDc6dosUHGcdMTQVCLeAObyuNXgk03LebCNogQCVKqcVHHgrZ3dvQN4skA))

```js
/** @template U */
class Bar {
    /** @typedef {Partial<U>} MyFoo */
    //                   ^^^--------------- Static members cannot
    //                                      reference class type parameters

    /** @type {string} */
    static someStaticProperty = "hello";
}
```

Which can be fixed by inserting a dummy property:

```js
/** @template U */
class Bar {
    /** @typedef {Partial<U>} MyFoo */

    nonStatic = "hello";

    /** @type {string} */
    static someStaticProperty = "hello";
}
```

I figured this is probably a bug, so [I reported it to the TypeScript team](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47215), but it got closed as working as intended. Before I start making a fool of myself and demanding it to get reopened, I figured I'd ask here first:

Is there a relation between `@typedef` and static properties that warrants this behaviour, or is this a bug?

Comment: I poked at this a bit, [it gets weirder](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?filetype=js#code/PQKhAIAEBcFMFsAOAbAhncAVcJgFgAoAYzQGdTwAxAe2vAG9DxnxQIYBPRWAE1gDMGABVQAnaAEtUyADyYAfAF9wAWQ406uJiwAe4ALzgAjACYAzIUWFCbKNC6wGajcq3FqAO1LRwew6YsCYGAWcAA9LAdwAHIPAFd4ACNYUWjwCQoPah9UcgkAcw9URORHaDp7bhiRcSlZBWiAOgAKcxMTAEogA)... TS in JS is a scary place.

Comment: Wow what, `MyFoo` shouldn't even be available outside that scope.